# How to implement the SNMP protocol in ThingsBoard IoT platform?

Tags: snmp, dashboard, thingsboard

I am intend to use the SNMP agent to access values from a board, and visualise them in ThingsBoard dashboard. Have anyone an idea how to support that protocol in the ThingsBoard?

Comment: How is that related to OPC UA?

Comment: Your entire question should read "How to visualize data in ThingsBoard" and the only tags should be "thingsboard" "visualization".

Comment: Sorry guy, I am noob in this website, but I think my question should be "Can I add the SNMP to thingsboard as an extension?". Can you answer this question?

Comment: I don't know, but in such case edit your post -- change the title, body and tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no SNMP support on Thingsboard. You will need to implement your own extension/adapter.

You could either use one of [Thingsboard API](https://thingsboard.io/docs/api) (mqtt, http, CoAp or mqtt-gateway).
Or code your on extension directly inside [Thingsboard IoT Gateway](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard-gateway) (Java).

Comment: The problem that I don't know if it gonna work or no! I didn't find any other extension rather than mqtt or http. have you any tutorial or guide for help?